# Render window broken

Tags: rendering, interface

I have made my render window broken by accident. Now it only shows vertical stripes. It seems the vertical dimension is infinite. Probably I have clicked somewhere or hit a key. Does anybody have an idea how I can switch back to normal view?

[screenshot http://imageshack.com/a/img820/1886/rkoo.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img820/1886/rkoo.png)

Comment: Do you have any composite nodes?

Comment: @ Joseph Tannhuber. The easiest way to help you is if you provide additional information on your render settings, but even better would be if you upload your blend file. You can use pasteall.org and attach the link in your question.